# Error in PHPUnit QueryDataSet not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this error when running PHPUnit tests on the Mac terminal:

`Error: Class 'PHPUnit\DbUnit\Dataset\QueryDataSet' not found`

I have found this file in my project file in the server, so I'm not understanding what might have caused this error. I have no errors (using PHPStorm) for the `public final function getDataSet() {`function for the base unit test of my project. I have also deleted composer within the project directory in the server and reinstalled.

Comment: This issue has been resolved.